# Can anyone assist me in the translation of this vertical inscription and the oval seal positioned below it?

Tags: translation, characters, character-identification, seal, calligraphy

This text is inscribed to the left on my calligraphy style zen Buddhist painting. I guess this could be considered running script. There is an oval shaped, white character seal located directly below. There are also two (Ying,Yang) seals on the right that have been identified as being quotes from Confucianism. However I've been getting contradictory responses for this one.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but here's my guess:

First 2 characters seem to be 辛未, which can refer to year 1991/1931/1871/... in Chinese [ganzhi system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexagenary_cycle). Most likely it's 1991.

The next two are 六月, the 6th month, aka June. Not sure if it's Gregorian calendar or Lunar calendar.

The 5th character is 三(three), followed by a horizontal line that got me confused bc it looks too long to be a 一(one). Maybe it's just a divider line but that would also be weird in a calligraphy work.

Below the horizontal line are three characters X生書. I can't identify the first one but most likely it's the surname of the artist. X生 is similar to Mr.X . 書(the traditional form of 书) means write. So X生書 means "written by Mr.X"

Edit: I saw your post about the seal below (you really should've put two pictures together) and that helps a lot. I think the X above is 铁, maybe 铁生 is the name of the artist.

Comment: Thanks Jason! You're the best I plan on posting the full in image once I can get these photos resized let me know if you come up with anything new edit it and send it to me

Answer (score 1):

Calligraphy:

> 辛未六月三心鉄（鐵）生書
> *Written by* 三心 ([Buddhism: Three Minds](https://www.nichirenlibrary.org/en/dic/Content/T/139)) 鐵生 (name) *on the sixth month of the year of [xīnwèi](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%BE%9B%E6%9C%AA).*

Seal:

> 畢*銕（鐵）生印
> *Seal of* 畢鐵生

---

*Reference for 「畢」:

<kbd>[春秋](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_and_Autumn_period)
[金](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_bronze_inscriptions)
[image: 畢]
郘⿱⿰启弋黑鐘
[集成226](http://www.guoxuedashi.net/yzjwjc/?bh=226&jgwfl=)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge and expertise.  Is there a possibility that the name could be written as